# Are the actors speaking Japanese in Solar Crisis?

Tags: dubbing, solar-crisis

I have been watching [*Solar Crisis* (1990)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Crisis_(film)) and it seems to be completely dubbed. The mouth movements have that Godzilla-like anti-synchronization.

However, many of the actors, like Charleton Heston, Tim Matheson and Jack Palance are Americans. Are they actually speaking Japanese in the film? If so, does that mean they memorized all their lines in Japanese?